# How can you dry code this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on js game and I feel like i'm reapeting a lot of code. Is there anyway to make the code more optimized or make it one big function? I hope this is enough code, if not I'll make a jfiddle with all the code.

```
// Shop, Double coffee
$("body").on("click", "#shopUpgradeDoublepoints", function() {
    if(storeDoublePoints === false && totalClicks >= storeDoublePointsCost) {
        storeDoublePoints = true;
        storeReleventCheckMultiplier = true;
        storeCurrentActive = "storeDoublePoints";
        storeBoughtItems.push("upgradeDoublePoints");
        totalClicks -= storeDoublePointsCost;
        storeReleventMultiplier();
        $("#shopUpgradeDoublepoints").fadeOut();
        $(".clicks").html(totalClicks);
        console.log("Unlocked doublepoints for " + storeDoublePointsCost + " coffee. Total coffee: " + totalClicks);
    }
});

// Shop, Triple coffee
$("body").on("click", "#shopUpgradeTriplepoints", function() {
    if(storeTriplePoints === false && totalClicks >= storeTriplePointsCost) {
        storeTriplePoints = true;
        storeCurrentActive = "storeTriplePoints";
        storeBoughtItems.push("upgradeTriplePoints");
        totalClicks -= storeTriplePointsCost;
        storeReleventMultiplier();
        $(".clicks").html(totalClicks);
        $("#shopUpgradeTriplepoints").fadeOut();
        console.log("Unlocked triplepoints for " + storeTriplePointsCost + " coffee. Total coffee: " + totalClicks);
    }
});

// Shop, Quadruple coffee
$("body").on("click", "#shopUpgradeQuadruplepoints", function(){
    if(storeQuadruplePoints === false && totalClicks >= storeQuadruplePointsCost) {
        storeQuadruplePoints = true;
        storeCurrentActive = "storeQuadruplePoints";
        storeBoughtItems.push("upgradeQuadruplePoints");
        totalClicks -= storeQuadruplePointsCost;
        storeReleventMultiplier();
        $("#shopUpgradeQuadruplepoints").fadeOut();
        $(".clicks").html(totalClicks);
        console.log("Unlocked quadruplepoints for " + storeQuadruplePointsCost + " coffee. Total coffee: " + totalClicks);
    }
});
```

Comment: if it is your working code you want reviewed you should look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nope just this piece of code

Comment: This question belongs to codereview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put all your data in an array of objects and then loop over them and process in them one function, something like this,

```
var items = [{
    name: "Double",
    points: false,
    pointsCost: 1234
}, {
    name: "Triple",
    points: true,
    pointsCost: 1234
}, {
    name: "Quadruple",
    points: false,
    pointsCost: 1234
}];


for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    processItem(items[i]);
}

function processItem(item) {
    var name = item.name + "points";
    var id = "#showUpgrade" + name;
    $("body").on("click", id, function() {
        if (!item.points && totalClicks >= item.pointsCost) {
            item.points = true;
            storeCurrentActive = "store" + name;
            storeBoughtItems.push("upgrade" + name);
            totalClicks -= item.cost;
            storeReleventMultiplier();
            $(".clicks").html(totalClicks);
            $(id).fadeOut();
            console.log(`Unlocked ${name} for ${item.cost} coffee. Total coffee: ${totalClicks}`);
            //console.log("Unlocked " + name + " for " + item.cost + " coffee. Total coffee: " + totalClicks);
        }
    });
}
```